# why eles.breadthFirstSearch() is behaving like dfs?

Tags: cytoscape.js

I used the following script for using the bfs function.

```
$(loadCy = function(){

  options = {
    showOverlay: false,
    minZoom: 0.5,
    maxZoom: 2,

    style: cytoscape.stylesheet()
      .selector('node')
        .css({
          'content': 'data(name)',
          'font-family': 'helvetica',
          'font-size': 24,
          'text-outline-width': 3,
          'text-outline-color': '#888',
          'text-valign': 'center',
          'color': '#fff',
          'width': 'mapData(weight, 30, 80, 20, 50)',
          'height': 'mapData(height, 0, 200, 10, 45)',
          'border-color': '#fff'
        })
      .selector(':selected')
        .css({
          'background-color': '#000',
          'line-color': '#000',
          'target-arrow-color': '#000',
          'text-outline-color': '#000'
        })
      .selector('edge')
        .css({
          'width': 2,
          'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle'
        })
    ,

    elements: {
      nodes: [
        {
          data: { id: 'j', name: 'Jerry', weight: 65, height: 174 }
        },

        {
          data: { id: 'e', name: 'Elaine', weight: 48, height: 160 }
        },

        {
          data: { id: 'k', name: 'Kramer', weight: 75, height: 185 }
        },

        {
          data: { id: 'g', name: 'George', weight: 70, height: 150 }
        }
        ,
        {
          data: { id: 'h', name: 'Hag', weight: 70, height: 150 }
        }
        ,
        {
          data: { id: 'i', name: 'Iam', weight: 70, height: 150 }
        }
      ],

      edges: [

        { data: { source: 'j', target: 'e' } },
        { data: { source: 'j', target: 'k' } },


        { data: { source: 'e', target: 'j' } },
        { data: { source: 'e', target: 'k' } },
        { data: { source: 'e', target: 'g' } },

        { data: { source: 'k', target: 'j' } },
        { data: { source: 'k', target: 'e' } },
        { data: { source: 'k', target: 'g' } },
        { data: { source: 'h', target: 'g' } },
       { data: { source: 'j', target: 'h' } },
       { data: { source: 'g', target: 'i' } }

      ],
    },

    ready: function(){
      cy = this;
      cy.$('#j').bfs(function(i, depth){
        console.log('visits ' + this.id()+depth);

}, false);
    }
  };

  $('#cy').cytoscape(options);

});
```

#### Output on console

- visits j0
- visits h1
- visits g2
- visits i3
- visits k1
- visits e1

#### But expected output should be something like

- visits j0
- visits h1
- visits k1
- visits e1
- visits g2
- visits i3

Am i missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've found a bug.  That particular one has been fixed in the 2.2 branch for the soon upcoming 2.2 release.  That branch also has better unit tests (incl. for bfs).  You can wait until 2.2 is released, or you can `gulp build` on the branch to get a snapshot build now.